# Jquery click event not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I have a button with a function binded to the click event. In desktop browser it works fine, but I can't make it work in my iOS device. This is the html:

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-3x custom-close" id="olivares-close">
```

And this is the javascript:

```
$('#olivares-close').click(function(){
  $('#olivares').slideUp('slow', function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize.px.parallax');
  });
});
```

I have also tried this JS:

```
$('#olivares-close').on('click touch', function(){
  $('#olivares').slideUp('slow', function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize.px.parallax');
  });
});
```

None of these works on mobile. I also tried with events `'touchstart'` and `'touchend'`, did not work. I also tried using `.bind()` instead of `.on()`.

I also tried using Jquery mobile `.on('tap',function(){...});` but did not work either (Also , I prefer not to include jquery mobile since i don't use it anywhere else in the web and I do not want to make it too heavy for loading)

I also tried wrapping my `<i>` element inside a `<a></a>` element and bind the click function to the `<a>`, but that did not work neither.

Every other click functions works perfectly on mobile, the only issue is with this one.

EDIT: The html container where my element is, is initially hidden with `display:none`

Thanks !

Comment: If the content is dynamicly loaded, you need to do $('#divid').trigger('create') on the parent div

Comment: It is not dynamicaly loaded, but when the website loads it is inside a hidden div. Do I still need to run that line? Where? In the function that shows the hidden div ?

Comment: Could be your custom close element is behind other elements, try adding `.custom-close{position: relative; z-index:10000;}`, or only `z-index` if it already has position other than static.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to include jQuery Mobile try using vclick event instead click. The jQuery Mobile "vclick" event handler simulates the "onclick" event handler on mobile devices. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What I found worked for Android devices was this:

js.executeScript("$('# pageElement .elementClassName').trigger('touchstart')");

I haven't had a chance to test on IOS yet but it may be worth a shot.